# How to increase line distance for equations written inside text

Tags: math-mode, line-spacing, text

This must have been asked before, but I don't manage finding an answer.

Say I got some text and an equation inside:

```
....    text    ....
....    text    ....
text $equation$ text % text line with equation
....    text    ....
....    text    ....
```

How do I locally increase the line distance where the equation is places?

Background: Sometimes the eq. is pretty large and scratches the line.

---

Off-Topic: Also I'm not finding an answer to this question even though I have seen it some time ago! (My search algorithm seems unsorted):

How to always write text as text in math environment? By that I mean not to always put `\text{}` around text in math equation. Instead it's automatically set.

Comment: What is meant by "scratches the line"? Can you show an example?

Comment: If equation is big, you should consider to write it as display math. Equation in text never "scratch" lines above/below them, rather increase space between those text lines. Please provide MWE, which reproduce your problem and show its compilation result.